# Convert space separated value text to .csv with c++ then save it

Tags: c++, ascii, export-to-csv, save-as, filesaver.js

How to convert .asc file (space separated value) into .csv file with c++ then save it as .csv file on pc or android.

Note: this .asc file is for srtm data, so it is large, is 3600 rows and 3600 columns.
Please without software like excel or such.
I searched in google but no result

**Edit**

See the figure to see the example [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhHBH.jpg)

the .asc file:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 4 5 5 6 6 6 6 5 5 4 3 3 2 3 5 6 7 7 8 9 10 10 10 11 12 11 10 10 11 13 14 14 14 13 13 12 12 11 11 11 11 11 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 13 14 13 13 13 14 14 14 14 14 15 15 14 14 14 15 15 14 14 16 17 18 20 23 27 31 32 35 38 41 43 44 46 47 48 50 50 49 49 50 51 51 54 55 56 58 59 59 61 62 62 62 61 58 54 53 52 52 51 51 53 54 53 51 50 50 49 49 50 51 52 53 53 52 51 51 52 57 62 61 59 57 57 57 60 60 60 59 58 58 58 58 57 57 57 61 63 64 62 -32768
 then new line
and other number follow the same patttern number of data spaced by a space

**Note**
It look likes as in figure

I know just so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

  ofstream file;

  file.open ("example.txt");

  file << "Please write this data to a file using C++\n";

  file.close();

  return 0;

}
```

but not reading then converting

Comment: Is there any text in your .asc file? Can you add some sample data from your .asc file?

Comment: I edited and put an example but I can post an image

Comment: Can you add that as text so that I can copy it?

Comment: Yes, the order is as in figure illustrated

Comment: What is your expected output? Because every numeric values are also separated by space. A csv file content are like ncols,180,nrows,144....

Comment: My expected output, that it should be commas between all these data, not space. one can simply do it by excel by choosing delimiter as "space" but I àsk for a c++ code doing this

Comment: I posted what I can do and what I know, as attempt. I hope no downvote

Comment: Do you need a output like: ncols,180,nrows,144,xllcorner,35.860138888900,yllcorner,34.419583333300,cellsize,0.000277777778,NODATA_value,-32768,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,5,5,4,3,3,2,3,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,10,10,11,12,11,10,10,11,13,14,14,14,13,13,12,12,11,11,11,11,11,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,13,14,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,14,14,14,15,15,14,14,16,17,18,20,23,27,31,32,35,38,41,43,44,46,47,48,50,50,49,

Comment: Yes, that is what I would know it, but not in console, but as a saved file on pc or on android. you can ignore the words so just starting with array numbers

Comment: Is it a valid constraint assuming that data will be separated by a single space character?

Comment: Yes, to open it with other program on android like ms excel that can support more than 3600 columns, but so as space separated value I can open it with other csv/excel opener in android choosing "space" as delimiter but they clopp some of columns, they dont support 3600 columns and more. and online to convert it, is slow and they are many files, so my solution was to convert it to "comma" separated with c++ then save it on machine. finally I can open it with MS Excel android and no matter about column number

Comment: Hi I have developed two program in C++, use the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a small C++ program which will solved your requirement.

```
int main()
{
   std::ifstream ascfile;
   std::ofstream csvFile;
   ascfile.open("source.asc");
   csvFile.open("output.csv");

    if (ascfile.is_open())
        {
            std::string line;
            while(std::getline(ascfile, line))
            {
                int p = 0;
                while ((p = line.find(' ', p)) != std::string::npos)
                {
                   line.insert(p, ",");
                   p += 2;
                }
                 csvFile << line <<std::endl;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry, the file could not be openend." << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
   ascfile.close();
   csvFile.close();
   return 0;
}
```

add header file iostream, fstream, string

Hi I modified the above program below as above program do not replace the space use the below program instead but must add header file :-

```
int main()
{
   std::ifstream ascfile;
   std::ofstream csvFile;
   ascfile.open("source.asc");
   csvFile.open("output.csv");

    if (ascfile.is_open())
        {
            std::string line;
            while(std::getline(ascfile, line))
            {
                std::replace( line.begin(), line.end(), ' ', ',');
                csvFile << line <<std::endl;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry, the file could not be openend." << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
   ascfile.close();
   csvFile.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, but I got error by running both code: replace was not declared in this scope.

Comment: I search for it in google

Comment: You should add header file <algorithm>

Comment: Thank you, I have already found the solution then included it, thank you again

Comment: But why all this downvote :(

Comment: Its not me. There are verity of people here. Some of them are here only to down vote :-)

Comment: I was also banned from another account to post, just bcz I asked, my question was unclear, but I edited it. I was surprised that I was banned to ask more :( I dont know what I should do, therefore I am here anonymous user. thank you again I will soon test your code to see the result :)

Comment: I want to tell you that it works perfectly, I dont know how much I should thank you, I upvoted your answer but no reputation :(

Comment: Its OK no problem. I am happy that it solved your problem :-)

Comment: I feel ashamed of you if I tell you, I have asked other question here but not yet answer. that was a code of github, converts .hgt files into .json, do you know about it? if yes; the question is here asked, if you have time and if not, not problem, thank you again, regards from Germany

Comment: you can provide me the link I will check.

Comment: thank you, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270036/extracting-data-from-hgt-files